# Caching an HttpResult/memorystream using newer CacheControl attribute

Tags: caching, servicestack

I just discovered the new CacheControl Attribute and it's working well for standard POCOs - I was wondering if something different was required to cache a service that returned an HttpResult as a PDF. (The service is working but I don't see any records in my cache after the service is called).

```
[Authenticate]
[CacheResponse(Duration = CacheExpirySeconds.TwentyFourHours)]  
public class AdvReportPDFService : Service
{
    public object Get(AdvRptPitchPercentages request)
    {
        var ms = SomeFunctionThatReturnsAMemoryStream();

        ms.Position = 0;
        return new ServiceStack.HttpResult(ms, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack's Cache isn't able to cache the metadata in a `HttpResult` that's defined in your Service Implementation (when returning Cached Responses). Instead you should use the `[AddHeader]` Request Filter Attribute to specify the custom ContentType your Service returns and return the naked Stream instead, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
[AddHeader(ContentType = "application/pdf")]
[CacheResponse(Duration = CacheExpirySeconds.TwentyFourHours)]  
public class AdvReportPDFService : Service
{
    public object Get(AdvRptPitchPercentages request)
    {
        var ms = SomeFunctionThatReturnsAMemoryStream();
        return ms;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Addheader attribute works the first time but not the second - when returning the cached response, the ContentType comes back as text/plain, and my PDF doesn't render in the browser correctly